# Mysql SELECT query returns false when ran in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I'm trying:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
$usernames_results = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id = $member_id") or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
while($user_row = $username_results->fetch_object()) {
// do stuff with$user_row
}
```

This always returns FALSE. I'm certain $member_id is not null and that it does exist in the database. I ran the SQL query directly on the database and it returns the correct result. The error I get is

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object`

when calling `fetch_object()` on `$usernames_results`.

$mysqli is also defined correctly because this works:

```
$conversations_results = $mysqli->query("SELECT UserID, ConversationID FROM Conversation_Members WHERE UserID = $user_id");
```

I have tried looking at `$mysqli->error` but it's empty.

What am I doing wrong in the first query?

This question has been wrongly marked duplicate before. Please do not mark this as a duplicate unless you're certain the suggested duplicate answers my problem.

Comment: `$member_id` is integer? Have you ran it on mysql?

Comment: Can you show other syntax of `$usernames_results` ?

Comment: check whether username and user_id exists in users table

Comment: This information is incomplete to understand your problem!! Can you post your full code along with the value of`$member_id`

Comment: @b0s3 yes. I output $member_id and ran the query on MySQL with the output value and it returned the correct result.

Comment: @YourCommonSense the suggested duplicate doesn't answer my question. Please reopen this question.

Comment: try to print "SELECT UserID, ConversationID FROM Conversation_Members WHERE UserID = $user_id"

Comment: or try to run it on phpmyadmin or in database directly

Comment: @apm I did do that and that query works.

Comment: show your full code including which MySQL API you are using to connect with. `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? check for errors on PHP and the query also

Comment: @Fred-ii- please check the edits.

Comment: ahem `$usernames_results` and `$username_results->fetch_object()` - having used error reporting, it would have thrown an undefined variable notice. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: question answered I do believe ^ *si?*

Comment: @YoussefSami if my comments above solved it, let me know. If so, you can either delete your question, or I will reopen it and reclose it with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index which is more appropriate, should that be the case. You didn't say anything, so I am moving on. Cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- it did indeed solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome Youssef. I reopened and reclosed, *cheers* glad it got resolved.